# problems of ipc communication in electronjs

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, electron

I am building an app which basically reads an sqlite3 database file. I have two render processes. Both the render processes are created in the main process. The second render process is created by a particular button click in the first render process upon which the first render process  sends an ipcRenderer.send() message to the main process.

My code was able to create the second render process but it couldn't get access to the data that it was supposed to get. This is my first question and i am sorry it lacks some protocol.

first snippet is the code in the main process (app.js)

```
database.all(`SELECT _table_Name as name, _table_json as json
    FROM _table_main WHERE _table_Name = "EWS Equipment Status    Recording"`, (err, rows) => {

if (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}


mainWindow.webContents.send('query:ResultRows', rows);
});
```

// the second snippet is the first render process

```
    ipcRenderer.on('query:ResultRows',(event,rows) => {

   var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   var t = document.createTextNode(rows[0].name);
   btn.appendChild(t);
   document.body.appendChild(btn);

   var test = rows;
   btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

   ipcRenderer.send('show:popUpContents', test);

   console.log(rows);


   });
   });
```

now on the main process (app.js) listens to the second snippet

```
    ipcMain.on('show:popUpContents',(event,test) =>{

    popWindow = new BrowserWindow({ });


    popWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'pop-up.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
    }));


    popWindow.webContents.send('get:popUpContents', test);
    console.log(test);
    console.log(popWindow.webContents);
    popWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    });
```

// now the second render process opens but it has no access to the 'test' variable nor does it print the console.log inside the block.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyBA6.png)

```
     ipcRenderer.on('get:popUpContents',(event,test) => {
     debugger;
     console.log(test);
     console.log('hellow world');
   });
   console.log('outside function');
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this on my own one day later. One needs to wait for a 'ready-to-load' event of the new browser window before making it listen for an incoming message.